Who to override a method of template class with different sub classes of parameters in sub classes
The compiler throw an error that the doSomething method in the SubSubClass does not override or implement a method from a supertype. How to fix the code? Pls note that I need the override in the SubSubClass since the doSomething method is being called in the BaseSuperClass
// Define the base parameter class
class BaseParameter {
    // Base parameter properties and methods
}

// Define the base superclass with a generic type parameter
abstract class BaseSuperClass<T extends BaseParameter> {
    // Abstract method to be implemented by subclasses
    public abstract void doSomething(T x);
}

// Define the sub-parameter class extending the base parameter
class SubParameter extends BaseParameter {
    // Sub-parameter properties and methods
}

// Define the subclass extending the base superclass with SubParameter
class SubClass extends BaseSuperClass<SubParameter> {
    @Override
    public void doSomething(SubParameter x) {
        // Implementation for SubParameter
    }
}

// Define the sub-sub-parameter class extending the sub-parameter
class SubSubParameter extends SubParameter {
    // Sub-sub-parameter properties and methods
}

// Define the sub-subclass extending the subclass with SubSubParameter
class SubSubClass extends SubClass {

    @Override
    public void doSomething(SubSubParameter x) {
        // Implementation for SubSubParameter
        super.doSomething(x);
    }
}


One possible solution is to match the signature of doSomething in SubSubClass to match the method in SubClass and then cast and use the parameter as need be. Is there any other way to achieve the same without the need of casting which cannot guarantee 100% type safety
class SubSubClass extends SubClass {

    @Override
    public void doSomething(SubParameter x) {
        // Implementation for SubSubParameter
        super.doSomething(x);
        if (x instanceof SubSubParameter){
            doSomthingElse((SubSubParameter)x);
        }
    }
}


It sounds like you want to declare SubClass as class SubClass<T extends SubParameter> extends BaseSuperClass<T>?

It also needs to be abstract.
If you extend an abstract class or implement an interface, but you don't
implement all of the abstract methods, then the sub-class must be declared as abstract.
abstract class BaseSuperClass<T extends BaseParameter> {
    // Abstract method to be implemented by subclasses
    public abstract void doSomething(T x);
}

// Define the sub-parameter class extending the base parameter
abstract class SubParameter extends BaseParameter {
    // Sub-parameter properties and methods
}

You could also turn these into interfaces since they are only defining an API.
interface BaseSuperClass<T extends BaseParameter> {   
    void doSomething(T x);
}

// Define the sub-parameter class extending the base parameter
interface SubParameter extends BaseParameter {
    // Sub-parameter properties and methods
}

In this case, SubParameter is already abstract since it's an interface, so no need to declare it as such.
Furthermore, since SubParameter doesn't add anything it's basically a marker interface, which has debatable value.
